# Loop with list of variables for multiple glm objects in R

Tags: r, loops, glm

I can not for the life of me see why this isn't working for me in R:(

```
## Unadjusted model 
noadj_var <- list("a",
                  "b",
                  "c",
                  "d",
                  )

for (i in 1:length(noadj_var)) {
  paste0("unadjusted_model_",i) <- glm(
    df$dependent_variable ~ i,
    data = df[df$present_2018 == "Yes" , ],
    family = binomial(link=logit),
    na.action = na.exclude
  )
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = df$dependent_variable ~ i, data = df[df$present_2018 ==  : 
 variable lengths differ (found for 'i')
```

I don't understand why I get this error when I have na.action = na.exclude

Is there something else that is being messed up?

Just to preface this the variable names "a", "b", "c" are not the real names, and I can't just change them to a sequence, it needs to be a list of strings.

Comment: it is not working because its just not correct. Try `paste0('a',1) <- 1` and see what happens.

Comment: Also `i` is just a number. you are creating a formula of ` df$dependent_variable ~ i` that `i` does not change in the formula. it is just `i`. Everything is just wrong with the syntax. One logic failure is I hope for every subset, the dependent variable has 2 groups

Comment: Of course it's incorrect, otherwise it would work. I came here because I don't know how to solve it. I would be extremely happy if instead of just saying it was wrong, someone could point me towards a resource that details how to do it right.

Comment: The problem is the logic. Explain what you want to do. its difficult to "guess" exactly what you are trying to do from an incorrect code

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to do the same operation (create a glm-object) with the same dependent variable, but a range of independent variables - in order to create an object for each glm. I want to do this with a loop.

Comment: `lapply(noadj_var, function(x) glm(reformulate(x, dependent_variable), binomial(logit), data, subset = present_2018 == 'Yes')` try this out and tell us whether it produces a list firs of all

Comment: Unforunately it doesn't finish

Comment: what of `glm(reformulate(noadj_var[[1]], dependent_variable), binomial(logit), data, subset = present_2018 == 'Yes')`

Comment: where i put `dependent_variable` put the name of the varible there if the name of the dependent varibale is `"dependent_variable"` then put that

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with the `purrr` package:

```
 list("a",
       "b",
       "c",
       "d",
  ) %>% 
    purrr::set_names(paste0("unadjusted_model_", .)) %>% 
    purrr::map(~glm(reformulate(.x, 'dependent_variable'),data = df),
               family = binomial(link=logit),
               na.action = na.exclude ) %>% 
    purrr::map(broom::tidy)
```